# Convert ical time to milliseconds

Tags: java, android, time, icalendar

I am trying to parse an iCal-file and write the info to a database for my Android application.

I am using the **ical4j-library** to parse the data, and as output I get, for example, a date formatted like this: **20140116T121500Z**.

I want to convert that date into milliseconds. I tried using Joda, but couldn't get it to work:

Caused by: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Invalid format: "20140110T091500Z" is malformed at "1500Z"

Comment: Need to parse Date or to get MS from the given date?

Comment: I need MS, parsed from the "20140116T121500Z"-string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) API for [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ");
System.out.println(formatter.parseDateTime("20140116T121500Z").getMillis());
```

**Output:**

> 1389874500000

I am able to parse your date through [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) by escaping 'Z' representing the timezone (or omit Z altogether):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
System.out.println(dateFormat.parse("20140116T121500Z").getTime());
```

**Output:**

> 1389854700000

**Note:** The difference in the 2 times is introduced by diluting the timezone in `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, which can be overcome by setting an explicit GMT timezone below:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.parse("20140116T121500Z").getTime());
```

**Output:**

> 1389874500000

Comment: Why different output between Joda-Time and java.text.SimpleDateFormat? Shouldn't we get the same number of milliseconds in both cases?

Comment: **Error** You used "hh" (meaning half-day 12-hour time) where you should have used "HH" (meaning full-day 24-hour time, 00-23). This applies to both cases, Joda-Time and the old java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks I have corrected that (and for the edits). The difference is the dilution introduced by ignoring the timezone in SimpleDateFormat (the effective difference is 5.5 hours - the difference in IST and Zulu)

Comment: So java.text.SimpleDateFormat ignores the "Z" and uses the default (or set) time zone to interpret the date-time string? Yet another reason to use Joda-Time instead.